# How do I output task title on simple_calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have tasks table and I have no clue how to output it in the simple calendar, can somebody help me with it?

```rb
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.text "content"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.datetime "datum"
end
```

And the `simple_calendar` I am using.

```
<%= month_calendar(attribute: :starts_at) do |date| %> 
  <%= date.day %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action set up your list of tasks to display...

```
@tasks = Task.all
```

In the view, tell the calendar what date value to use for the task, which looks like `datum`....

```
<%= month_calendar(attribute: :datum) events: @tasks do |date, tasks| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% tasks.each do |task| %>
    <div>
      <%= task.title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I still get an error saying "ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in TasksController#show"